# div title syntax in haml and also incorporate ruby variable inside it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have trouble converting HTML syntax into HAML.

I know a `<div>` class can be simply represented by:

```
.class-name
```

But, I want to convert the following syntax into HAML and also incorporate a variable in the title:

```
<div title="My title" class="my-text">This is my title</div>
```

Something like:

```
.title{@ruby-variable}.my-text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.my-text{:title => "My title"} This is my title
```

in haml you use `#someid.someclass{:custom_attr => "something"}`. `:costum_attr` can also be a class or a id if you need to define it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.my-text{:title => 'My title'} This is my title
```

Or another syntax:

```
.my-text(title = 'My title') This is my title
```

Answer (score 0):

A more modern syntax would be `.my-text{title: 'My title'} My text.`